# Subfigure error while using IEEEtran template

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, subfig

This is my tex to plot subfigures (I use overleaf):

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{image1.png}} 
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{image2.png}} 
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{image3.png}}
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{image4.png}}
\caption{caption text}
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}
```

I used these packages just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

I expect to have in one column of two-column page: 1234 images. So the images will be side by side in a single row. However, it produces each image one under the other to cover one column (= four rows). The error that I got (for each subfigure line) is

[image]

Comment: You should realize that `subfigure` has been obsolete for about 20 years; its replacement is `subfig` (with a slightly different syntax, namely `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure`). But you don't need subfigures if you don't have subcaptions with them. Also, as far as I know, `IEEEtran` uses two-column format. and you possibly want `figure*` (and no `[H]`), but also need to protect the endlines with `%`.

Comment: so I need to use subfig instead of subfigure and \subfloat instead of \subfigure?

Comment: See my answer to see what are two possible ways to do the job.

Answer (score 4):

You want `figure*`, if the figures have to fill the entire textwidth. I provide two ways, one without subcaptions, one with them.

Loading `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` is only needed for the second case. If you want also text near to the letters, type it in the optional argument

```
\subfloat[some text]{\includegraphics[...]{...}}%
```

In either case `%` at the end of lines is necessary to avoid a space creeping in. It's actually not needed in the second example, because `\subfloat` will remove a space preceding it.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure*}

\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}

\caption{caption text}\label{label}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum[8-14]

\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup{farskip=0pt,nearskip=4pt}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{caption text}\label{label2}

\end{figure*}

\lipsum[14-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For single column figures, here's the code, again with the two possibilities.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[htp]

\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}%
\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}

\caption{caption text}\label{label}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[8-10]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup{farskip=0pt,nearskip=4pt}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.25\columnwidth]{example-image}}

\caption{caption text}\label{label2}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[14-17]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I want to place 4 images in only 1 of 2 columns.

Comment: I used columnwidth instead of textwidth for the first option that you wrote. Unfortunately, I got the error: width=0.25\columnwidth is undefined..

Comment: @MasA I added the corresponding code for single-column figures.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried the new one but it always generates me the same error. Seems that it does not recognize width part. I use \documentclass[conference, a4paper]{IEEEtran} to be more clear and they are some predefined packages. I wonder if some of them cause a problem or something else..